# Unrecognized "Private Network IPs" that disappear when modem is unplugged from Internet

Tags: local-area-network, internet, arp

So my internet has been acting up at night very sporadically and tonight I decided to check out what was happening. (Mind you, I'm not very network-savy, but I'll try to explain as best as I can. My apologies beforehand!)

Here's what happened:

1. Internet stopped working.
2. I tried pinging `google.com` and it worked. No other website worked.
3. I log into my router (my network uses 10.0.0.1) and check my ARP list. I can see all my networks' devices (10.0.0.7, 10.0.0.9, etc.) *but there's also unrecognized IPs in there*. I see around 7 IPs within the 172.16.0.0 — 172.24.0. 0 space.
4. I try pinging them and it works. Two or three of them are running IIS webserver.
5. Just to verify, I physically unplug my modem from WAN (telephone line-like cable) and refresh the ARP list and these unrecognized IPs all vanished.
6. Connect to WAN again and the IPs reappeared.

I know that the 172.16 — 172.24 space is meant for use in private networks, but we've never used those spaces before. What could be happening here? Is there a chance someone gained access to my network and created a virtual network between us?

Don't want to come off too paranoid but I can't think of any other explanation. Hopefully, one of you will!

Comment: If you are getting ARPs of 172.16.x.x that means you have an IP in that network or people can broadcast in your VLAN. Is there another SSID? Or you sharing your broadcast with somebody else?

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra Not as far as I know. Could my ISP have configured it by default? Seems unlikely.

Comment: **I log into my router (my network uses 10.0.0.1) and check my ARP list. I can see all my networks' devices (10.0.0.7, 10.0.0.9, etc.) but there's also unrecognized IPs in there. I see around 7 IPs within the 172.16.0.0 — 172.24.0. 0 space.** -- oh so you said the ARPs of these IPs on your router? Did you check the wan interface and IP on that?

Comment: These IPs appear to be using the `ptm0.2` interface and they disappear once I unplug the internet cable. Not sure what else to check for in the ARP list.